# Amazon's anti-piracy: how many movies can $m$ conspirators leak?

Tags: reference-request, traitor-tracing

Is there any existing academic literature about this application of traitor tracing?

---

A video streaming service has a new anti-piracy technique to identify customers who capture and share their streamed videos. It goes something like the following:

- For each movie $\mathbf{M}$, there exist a number of distinct "editions" $\mathbf{M}_\alpha,\mathbf{M}_\beta,\dots$ which are practically indistinguishable to the naked eye, but robustly distinct (i.e. they *can* be discriminated with a high degree of confidence even after being downscaled or re-encoded once or twice)
- Each movie $\mathbf{M}$ is split by keyframes into a sequence of "scenes" $\mathbf{M}_1,\dots,\mathbf{M}_{fin}$. (For the sake of simplicity, assume all editions have keyframes at the same location.)
- When customer $\mathcal{C}_i$ requests movie $\mathbf{M}$, the service uses prf $F_\mathbf{M}:\mathcal{C}\to\{\mathbf{M}_\alpha,\mathbf{M}_\beta,\dots\}^{fin}$ to serve them a "personally-identifiable edition" $F_\mathbf{M}(\mathcal{C}_i)_1\parallel\dots\parallel F_\mathbf{M}(\mathcal{C}_i)_{fin}$

For the sake of generality, we'll fix $\mathbf{M}$ to be the concatenation of *all* licensed videos, in order of acquisition by the service, and think about long-term play.

If the service has $k$ editions of their movies, and $m<<n$ of the customers are pirates who have conspired to leak the maximum amount of contiguous scenes $\mathbf{M}_1,\mathbf{M}_2,\dots$ with none of them being personally-identifiable beyond some degree of confidence $\epsilon$, what is the maximum number of scenes they can leak?

Comment: In the literature, this sort of scheme is known as 'traitor-tracing', and has rather a lot of literature associated with it.  While I'm not that familiar with the best findings (hence this is not an answer), that's what you would search on.

Comment: @poncho thanks; that allowed me to refine the question to get more at what I'm trying to ask!

Comment: This is also known as “collusion-secure fingerprinting.” There are a number of papers on it in the literature.

Comment: Another keyword which seems fit with your goal : Watermarking.

Comment: @levgeni Indeed that is correct, though I assumed they would be using some form of watermarking to differentiate what's referred to in this post as "editions"